# My ascii value dictionary doesn't work

Tags: python, ascii

I got an assignment yesterday about Rot and I was told to write all 26 of them in code, or atleast a program that did, so I thought I'd start with the dictionary, since I wanted to also call for a certain rot I came up with this.

```
def generate_rotated_dictionary(n):
    for i in range(0, 26):
        letter = alphabet_list[i]
        new_let = ord(letter) + n
        new_let = chr(new_let)
        rot_dic.update({letter: new_let})
    return(rot_dic)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and results in:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'b': 'c', 'e': 'f', 'd': 'e', 'g': 'h', 'f': 'g', 'i': 
'j', 'h': 'i', 'k': 'l', 'j': 'k', 'm': 'n', 'l': 'm', 'o': 'p', 'n': 'o', 
'q': 'r', 'p': 'q', 's': 't', 'r': 's', 'u': 'v', 't': 'u', 'w': 'x', 'v': 
'w', 'y': 'z', 'x': 'y', 'z': '{'}

{'a': 'c', 'c': 'e', 'b': 'd', 'e': 'g', 'd': 'f', 'g': 'i', 'f': 'h', 'i': 
'k', 'h': 'j', 'k': 'm', 'j': 'l', 'm': 'o', 'l': 'n', 'o': 'q', 'n': 'p', 
'q': 's', 'p': 'r', 's': 'u', 'r': 't', 'u': 'w', 't': 'v', 'w': 'y', 'v': 
'x', 'y': 'z', 'x': 'z', 'z': '|'}

{'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e', 'e': 'h', 'd': 'g', 'g': 'j', 'f': 'i', 'i': 
'l', 'h': 'k', 'k': 'n', 'j': 'm', 'm': 'p', 'l': 'o', 'o': 'r', 'n': 'q', 
'q': 't', 'p': 's', 's': 'v', 'r': 'u', 'u': 'x', 't': 'w', 'w': 'z', 'v': 
'y', 'y': '|', 'x': 'z', 'z': '}'}

{'a': 'e', 'c': 'g', 'b': 'f', 'e': 'i', 'd': 'h', 'g': 'k', 'f': 'j', 'i': 
'm', 'h': 'l', 'k': 'o', 'j': 'n', 'm': 'q', 'l': 'p', 'o': 's', 'n': 'r', 
'q': 'u', 'p': 't', 's': 'w', 'r': 'v', 'u': 'y', 't': 'x', 'w': 'z', 'v': 
'z', 'y': '}', 'x': '|', 'z': '~'}
```

How do I fix it with the ending, I know that it is because of my use of Ascii values, but how do i get this to start with the a again (number 97)

Comment: What is `rot`? What does "doesn't work" mean? How does the output differ from what you want?

Comment: "I was told to write all 26 of them in code, " All 26 of what? Please be more specific and detailed so that we can help you.

Comment: Presumably he's talking about the [rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) cipher and its 25 other variants.

Answer (score 3):

So if you need to rotate alphabet you can use following method:

```
import string
alph = string.ascii_lowercase
for i in range(26):
    print(''.join([alph[(k + i) % 26] for k in range(26)]))
```

Output is alphabetic strings with offset:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc
.....
zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
```

If you need lists instead of strings just remove `join()`.
If you required some specific rotation like 13 then you can use this code inside function with argument:

```
def rot(i):
    return ''.join([alph[(k + i) % 26] for k in range(26)])
```

This will give rotation for specific number.
Example:

```
print(rot(13))
```

Output:

```
nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

n = 1
rot = dict((c, chr(97 + ((ord(c)-97 + n)%26) )) for c in l)
```

The comprehension there is a little dense, so lets break it down:

```
(c, chr(97 + ((ord(c)-97 + n)%26) ))
```

produces tuples of one character and its shifted counterpart

```
chr(97 + ((ord(c)-97 + n)%26) )
```

makes a character

```
97 + (ord(c)-97 + n)%26
```

get the value of the old character and calculate how many to shift over.

Comment: `l = map(chr,range(97,122))`

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to summarize, here's a full method:

```
# Generates a function which rotate a sequence by an offset
def generate_rot(seq, offset):
    l = len(seq)
    def rot(c):
        n = (seq.index(c) + offset) % l
        return seq[n]
    return rot

> alpha = map(chr,range(97, 123)) # [a...z]
> rot13 = generate_rot(alpha, 13)
> print(rot13('a'))
n
> print(rot13('n'))
a
> rot21 = generate_rot(alpha, 21)
v
```

You can then bind it to the alphabet, specifically:

```
> def generate_alpha_rot(x):
    return generate_rot(map(chr,range(97, 123)),x)
# or using a lambda function to create it inline, because why not?
> generate_alpha_rot = lambda x:generate_rot(map(chr,range(97, 123)),x)
> rot22 = generate_alpha_rot(22)
> rot22('a')
w
# Or call it inline:
> generate_alpha_rot(23)('a')
x
```

Answer (score -2):

Hardly worth a full answer, but you want to take the modulo 26 of `new_let` before you convert to a character. by doing remainder division, you get how far past 26 the index has gone

Consider:

```
>>>26 + 13 # rot13 for z
39
>>>39 % 26
13
```